# Constructor and Destructor for static member variable (a pointer)

Tags: c++, pointers, static, destructor, explicit-destructor-call

I am working on a class `ex1` which needs one static member variable `y`. That static member variable is a pointer to an object of class `ex2` which has its own constructor and destructor. Now I know how to initialize the variable `y` by defining it outside the class. But how to call the destructor for variable `y`? I need to use `delete` statement, but where to place that statement. I need to call both constructor and destructor of class `ex2`.

An equivalent code of my problem is shown below with the output:

```
#include<iostream>

class ex2 {
public:
  int n;
  ex2(int num) {
    n = num;
    std::cout << "Constructor of ex2\n";
  }
  ~ex2(){std::cout << "Destructor of ex2\n";}
};

class ex1 {
public:
  static ex2 *y;  //static member variable
  ex1() {std::cout << "Constructor of ex1\n";}
  ~ex1() {std::cout << "Destructor of ex1\n";}
};

ex2 *ex1::y = new ex2(90); //definition for static member

int main()
{
  ex1 y1;
  return 0;
}
```

The output for this is:

```
Constructor of ex2
Constructor of ex1
Destructor of ex1
```

Please help on how to call the destructor of `ex2`. Also the destructor need to be called after all instances of class `ex1` are destroyed.

Comment: Why not use `static std::unique_ptr<ex2> y;`.

Comment: Since the memory is allocated at static scope, it should be deleted at program exit, see also the [atexit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit) function. Or just use a smart pointer as @DavidSchwartz suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create regular class that on destructions calls `delete` on your pointer:

```
struct Destroyer {
    ex2 *p;
    ~Destroyer() { delete p; }
};

ex2 *ex1::y = new ex2(90);
Destroyer dex2{ex1::y};
```

PS: In my experience you should avoid putting too much logic during automatic initialization and automatic destruction. There are things to pay high attention to (what parts of your system are still usable when doing the destruction? what parts are already usable during construction?) and moreover I discovered even tools like debuggers don't work well during those times. As a rule for example you should never ever do anything that can fail for whatever reason before main is started or after main is completed because that will be a pain to manage (how can you log an error during initialization if the error logging subsystem wasn't initialized yet? how can you log the error during shutdown if the logging system was already shut down?).

I also think the C++ standard specification is kind of fuzzy about those issues so you may get surprises depending on compilers and over the years I preferred moving away from lazy/automatic initialization and destruction to explicit initialization and destruction done in `main` in the sequence I want and that I know to be correct.

Comment: Thank you. It works for me.
Also thanks for the useful advice. I will try to change my code.